# JSON getting nested in a POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a POJO class as:

```
public class D{

    private JSONObject profileData;


    public JSONObject getProfileData ()
    {
        return profileData;
    }

    public void setProfileData (JSONObject profileData)
    {
        this.profileData = profileData;
    }

}
```

Now I populate this class like:

```
for (int i =0; i<identities.size();i++){
            D d = new D();

            d.setProfileData(profileData);

            dList.add(d);
        }
```

I create JSON object for `profileData` from GSON using a HashMap:

```
profileDataInJson = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(map1));
```

Where the signature of profileDataInJson is:  `JSONObject profileDataInJson = null;`

Now the resultant JSON is like:

```
"profileData":{"map":{"ioCinema":"firstValue","ioSIMAvailable":"firstKey","Name":"onePair"}}
```

Wherein I get an unwanted object called map inserted in my main profileData object.

However when I print this inside the loop I get

```
{`"ioCinema":"firstValue","ioSIMAvailable":"firstKey","Name":"onePair"}`
```

Whish is exactly what I want inside profileData object, without nesting the `map` object.

How do I solve this?

"I am already aware that I can achieve this by converting the type of profileData in D class from JSONObject to String, which will induce escape characters - However I am looking for  a generic solution"

EDIT:

map1 is constructed in two ways, depending on user input and both ways are as follows:

```
if (args.length >= 4 && args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("onePair")) {

                    map1 = new HashMap<>();
                    String key1 = args[2];
                    String value1 = args[3];


                    map1.put(key1, value1);


                    profileDataInJson = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(map1));

                }
```

And:

```
if (args.length >= 1 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {

                if (args.length >= 2)
                    profileData.setName(args[1] != null ? args[1] : "");

                if (args.length >= 3)
                    profileData.setSIMAvailable(args[2] != null ? args[2] : "");
                  profileDataInJson = new JSONObject(profileData);
}
```

Signature:   `ProfileData profileData = new ProfileData();`

The thing which puzzles me is when I try to traverse profileData and try to fetch the json object by name "map" I get a nullPointer exception

Comment: Gson is not aware of `org.json.JSONObject` and serializes it as is by reflection according to its internal structure. Replace it with `com.google.gson.JsonObject`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Gson` to convert hashmap to a json object.
Simply use:

`profileDataInJson = new JSONObject(map);`

Comment: I am still getting the same result!

Comment: @User3 Can you post the code where you are constructing `map1` object?

Comment: @User3 You are still using the hashmap in the first if block, `if (args.length >= 4 && args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("onePair"))`

Comment: No this is sorted in the if conditions and the command line args

Comment: Oh I wrongly interpreted your query, I am using the GSON part, yes I was debugging when I edited the code above and had reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom serializer to Gson, so that Gson serialize the org JSON as expected by you.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(JSONObject.class, new JsonSerializer<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(final JSONObject src, final Type typeOfSrc,
                    final JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return new JsonParser().parse(src.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
            }
        });
gsonBuilder.create().toJson(map1);
```

This will return `{"ioCinema":"firstValue","ioSIMAvailable":"firstKey","Name":"onePair"}`